# ¿Como hacer un test unitario a un método que se conecta a una base de datos en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, c#-8.0

Buen dia. Soy nuevo realizando pruebas unitarias. Estoy trabajando en una libreria c#.
EL metodo que quiero testear consiste en que busca un cliente por su numero de identificacion si lo encuentra entonces trae un objeto de tipo persona si no lo encuentra trae el objeto vacio. Cabe resaltar que la informacion la esta buscando en una base de datos sqlServer. SI alguien pudiera orientarme como hacer esta prueba le agradeceria muchisimo. La verdad estuve buscando en internet y no se ni por donde comenzar y tengo varios metodos del mismo estilo se que haciendo uno podria entender la logica.

clase persona:

```
public class Persona
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage ="El campo Cedula es Obligatorio")]
    public string Cedula { get; set; }

    public string IdCupo { get; set; }

    public string Nombres { get; set; }

    public string PrimerApellido { get; set; }

    public string SegundoApellido { get; set; }

    public string Pagare { get; set; }

    public decimal ValorMinimo { get; set; }

    public decimal  ValorProximo { get; set; }

    public decimal  ValorTotal { get; set; }

    public string Telefono { get; set; }
}
```

Metodo ClienteRequest al que le quiero hacer el test unitario

```
public Persona BuscarCliente(string cedula)
    {
        Persona objPersona = new Persona();
        //string connection de la base de datos
        string connectionString
       = "server=;database=dbTestStudioPse;Trusted_Connection=True;integrated security = true";
        string selectQuery = "Cedula, IdCupo, Nombres, PrimerApellido, " +
            "           SegundoApellido, Pagare, ValorMinimo, ValorProximo, ValorTotal, Telefono";
        string query = $"select {selectQuery} from Persona where persona.Cedula = {cedula}";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command =  new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            string cedulaResult = "n";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Persona oPersona = new Persona();
                    oPersona.Cedula = reader.GetString(0);
                    oPersona.IdCupo = reader.GetString(1);
                    oPersona.Nombres = reader.GetString(2);
                    oPersona.PrimerApellido = reader.GetString(3);
                    oPersona.SegundoApellido = reader.GetString(4);
                    oPersona.Pagare = reader.GetString(5);
                    oPersona.ValorMinimo = reader.GetDecimal(6);
                    oPersona.ValorProximo = reader.GetDecimal(7);
                    oPersona.ValorTotal = reader.GetDecimal(8);
                    oPersona.Telefono = reader.GetString(9);

                    objPersona = oPersona;

                }
              
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Hay un error en la base de datos" + ex.Message);
            }

            return objPersona;
        }       

    }
```

Comment: No estas usando ningun framework para hacer las pruebas?

Comment: Ese método no aplica para test unitario. Debes hacer test unitario  a los métodos donde hay lógica de negocio. Y para métodos como este donde hay acceso a base de datos se hace un test de integración.

Comment: Ósea que tendría que hacer prueba unitaria es al controlador que consume esta librería?

Comment: Estaba intentando con Xunit

Comment: Podés recibir el objeto **Connection** como parametro ó en el constructor del objeto. De esta manera podes hacer una conexión a SQLite en los test y a SQLServer en producción.

Comment: Lee **DependencyInjection** (injección de dependencias). Te va a ayudar mucho para realizar los tests y mejorar el código. No necesitar frameworks para aplicar el padrón.

Answer (score 1):

Agrego un código para explicar mejor como es el proceso del unit testing, puede verse un poco complejo pero solo es cuestión de estudiarlo un poco.

El controlador `DemoController` llama al servicio `DemoService`.

`DemoService` contiene un objeto de tipo `IDemoData`, el cual es una interfaz no un tipo concreto.

`IDemoData` tiene un método `DoSomething()` el cual tiene dos implementaciones en: `DemoDataReal` y `FakeData`.

`DemoDataReal` accede a los datos reales que pueden estar en una base de datos ( como tu caso ), un web service etc.

`FakeData` no accede a servicios reales y esa clase usaremos para los test unitarios.

Al final está la clase `ResultMustBeFalseIfDataIsZero` la cual es un test unitario. Ahí se crea un objeto de `DemoService` y se le asigna un objeto de tipo `FakeData` para hacer las pruebas.

Lo importante en las pruebas unitarias es que el código a probar no tenga dependencias externas como bases de datos, por eso se usa `FakeData`, simula que devuelve un valor pero en ningún momento se accedió a la base de datos.

Por qué se hace el test a `DemoService`? es una buena práctica no poner la lógica de negocios en el controlador, de esa forma puede reusarse. El controlador solo debe encargarse de recibir peticiones y enviar respuestas, no debe saber de la lógica de negocios.

Te recomiendo leer el libro **The art of unit testing**

```
public class DemoController : Controller{
    
        private readonly DemoService service = new DemoService(new DemoDataReal());
    
        public ActionResult Index(){
    
            var result = service.DoSomething();
    
            ViewBag.result = result;
    
            return View();
        }
    }
    
    public class DemoService{
        private readonly IDemoData data;
    
        public DemoService(IDemoData data){
                this.data = data;
        }
        public bool DoSomething(){
    
            var result = data.GetData();
            bool response = false;
            // bussiness logic goes here
    
            if(result > 0 ) response = true;
    
    
            // return the business logic result
            return response;
        }
    }
    
    public interface IDemoData{
         int GetData();
    }
    
    public class DemoDataReal : IDemoData
    {
        public int GetData()
        {
            // connect to database, or web api , etc to get real data.
            return 9; // random response from the data repository
        }
    }
    
    public class FakeData : IDemoData
    {
        public int GetData()
        {
            return 0; // fake data for unit testing
        }
    }
    
    
    public class ResultMustBeFalseIfDataIsZero
        {
            private readonly DemoService service;
    
            public ResultMustBeFalseIfDataIsZero()
            {
                service = new DemoService(new FakeData());
            }
    
            [Fact]
            public void IsFalseIfDataIsZero()
            {
                var result = service.DoSomething();
    
                Assert.False(result, "result must be false");
            }
        }
```